# Do the finite groups of Lie type have infinite analogs?

Tags: group-theory, finite-groups, lie-groups, infinite-groups

Of the [18 infinite families](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_finite_simple_groups) of [finite simple groups](https://irandrus.files.wordpress.com/2012/06/periodic-table-of-groups.pdf), I know that $\mathbb{Z}$, the infinite analog of $\mathbb{Z}_p$, isn't simple while $A_\infty$, the one for $A_n$, is. What about the 16 families of groups of Lie type? Do they have infinite analogs, and are they simple?

I know that Lie groups proper are infinite (right?). Are any of them infinite analogs to the finite groups, and if so, which ones?

Comment: It’s not clear from your examples what you mean by “infinite analog.” Can you say something more precise here about what you’re looking for?

Comment: I know I'm probably asking something blindingly obvious, but I'm new to group theory and intensely curious.

Comment: @QiaochuYuan I'm not sure what I mean. I know that $\mathbb{Z}$ is the infinite cyclic group, and that $A_\infty$ is the infinite alternating group, but I'm not sure how to formalize those notions in relation to their finite counterparts.

Comment: Start thinking through the case of $A_n(q)$. The letter $A$ stands for the root system of type $A$ and the letter $n$ stands for rank. Do you know what would be the corresponding Lie groups? However, beyond Chevalley groups, the correspondence breaks down and your question has no meaningful answer.

Comment: Read this and see if you like the answer: https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2300268/connections-between-finite-and-lie-groups-in-fulton-and-harris?rq=1

Comment: In the logic direction, a keyword: "pseudofinite". "The analogue": these are some analogues, but not the only ones. For instance $Z/pZ$ has infinite analogues that are fields, check "pseudofinite field", while in ring theory, $Z$ is in many respects much more complicated than $Z/pZ$.